# Exctracting bought trauma book from xhtml referral

Tags: pdf, download

I am a ICU nurse and a little bit comfortable with computers.

I am going to do a trauma course and need to read a book. They gave me an eBook to read, however it is only accessible through a horrible site.

I am trying to grab the file so I can put it on my eReader. I did inspect with Google chrome and found it grabs the file from here. How am I able to download this (as a) pdf?

" src="https://openpage-ebooks.jblearning.com/op2_content/extracted_books/9781284184853-8.1.1/EPUB/xhtml/9781284180718_Title.xhtml" class="content-sandbox" style="height: 455px;">

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try asking your question on https://superuser.com/ where you're more likely to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The src attribute gives you the url of the ebook (or possibly embedded viewer?) in xhtml, so it is not a pdf or epub download link. I am guessing your ereader does not have a web broswer on it? If it does not, you have no guarantee that you can get it in a format compatible with your ereader. You might have to go to the network tab and see the request made. There will be authentication required with an auth token probably, because when I try to access the url it gives me a 403 forbidden.

Update: From the additional info and the structure of the url in the src attribute of the iframe tag, it seems like their server probably has each page of the ebook, extracted into xhtml from epub format, and is serving that to the webpage each time you change page. So there is no way to just get a pdf download directly from this page. From the info we have, in order to get a pdf, you would have to get each xhtml page getting loaded in the iframe (check the network tab to find the request for the page) and convert into the format your ereader requires. It is possible to convert from xhtml to pdf but I imagine it will be tedious and/or require scripting to find, download and convert every page (especially since you do not know every page's url beforehand). Sorry to disappoint.

Comment: And even then, you still might not be able to get a download of the file itself (depending on what the xhtml actually is)

Comment: I just wish to download it as pdf. I can load every page individually and it always refers to the xhtml page so I imagine it grabs the page from there through a secure connection. Thanks for thinking along :)

Comment: what is the beginning of the tag you posted in the question? (the bit before src, it will start with a "<")

Comment: <iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="100%" height="455" title="
Trauma Nursing Core Course: Provider Manual


" src="https://openpage-ebooks.jblearning.com/op2_content/extracted_books/9781284184853-8.1.1/EPUB/xhtml/9781284180718_Title.xhtml" class="content-sandbox" style="height: 455px;">
  </iframe>

Is this what you mean? I can download 2 pages a time as pdf but the book is 300 pages. I think this protected website makes it impossible for me

Comment: Yes, you would have to download and covert each of these two pages to pdf. Sorry.

Comment: Have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you! I did not expect to find a solution. All the best